# python3 RNG variables

Tags: python-3.x

been coding for 2 days and ran into a snag.

I wanted to make a fun little practice thingy to help some people practice their english.

Basically they type in the words they wanna practice and then the randomizer throws out sentences for them to read.

Issue is I want to get the grammer right, I have done two different "Pronoun" catagories and 2 different "verb" catagories.

How do I link them together but still retain the random element of never knowing what combo you would get but making it still follow the grammer rules.

Code is below, any help would be awesome =D

```
# coding: utf-8

# In[73]:

noun1 = ("apple", "peach", "plum", "cat", "dog", "mouse")
verb1 = ("drink", "eat", "swim", "kill", "kick", "hit", "die")
# verb + S 
verbS = ("drinks", "eats", "swims", "kills", "kicks", "hits", "dies")
adj1 = ("blue", "black", "red","big", "small", "tall", "short")
direction1 = ("up", "in", "out", "behind", "infront of", "over")
#pronouns Capital
Pronoun1 = ("I", "You", "They", "We")
PronounS = ("He", "She","Tt")
#pronouns non Capital
pronoun1 = ("I", "you", "they", "we")
pronounS = ("he", "she","it")

# In[74]:

import random

# In[75]:

def sentence1():
    print(random.choice(Pronoun1),end=" ")
    print(random.choice(verb1),end=" ")
    print("the",end=" ")
    print(random.choice(adj1),end=" ")
    print(random.choice(noun1),end=" ")
    return"."

# In[82]:

print(sentence1())
```

Comment: the code wasn't a "snippet" for SO

Comment: What do you mean? I have to upload less to ask wuestions?

Comment: The most relevant part is line 75 onwards

Comment: No, what you uploaded is okay, just the "begin/end snippet" marks are unsuitable for Python code, so I removed them.

Comment: Oh nice thanks a bunch :)